# How do I accept field arguments for a nested query in Graphql Ruby?

Tags: graphql, apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client, graphql-ruby

I'm getting this error in GraphQl (Apollo JS/ Graphql Ruby):
`Error Error: GraphQL error: Field 'pagination' doesn't accept argument 'pagination' GraphQL error: Variable $pagination is declared by Clients but not used. Reload the page and try again.`

I have this query:

```
query Clients($pagination: PaginationInput) {
  clients {
     data {
       ....Fragment
     }
     pagination(pagination: $pagination) {
       ....Fragment
     }

  }
}
```

And I have this as my input type:

```
class PaginatedClientsType < Types::BaseObject
   field :data, ...
   field :pagination, PaginationType ... do 
     argument :pagination, PaginationInput, required: false
   end
end
```

And this in my `query_type.rb` file:

```
field :clients, ::Types::Paginated::ClientsType, null: false do
   argument :pagination, PaginationInput, required: false
end

def clients(pagination:)
  ...
end

// and i've added to no avail:
field :pagination ... do
   argument :pagination, PaginationInput, required: false
end
def pagination(pagination:)
...
end
```

Any ideas on how I can pass the argument to something other than this top level `client`? 
I've read docs [here](https://github.com/rmosolgo/graphql-ruby/blob/master/guides/fields/introduction.md) but can't figure it out.

Thanks!

Comment: I just wanted to let you know that I've also had this problem and tried the same things you have and never figured out a way to do this

Comment: The way that you've written it actually looks correct. Any chance you could provide a dump of the schema?